# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(x+n)^2}{n^3}$ uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(x+n)^2}{n^3}$$

Is this series uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$ ?
I've already proven that it is uniformly convergent $[a,b]\subset \Bbb R$. And I don't think that it is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$, but I don't know how to show this. I thought about showing that for $N\in\Bbb N$ there exist $n,m :n\geq m>N$ and there exists $x\in R$ such that the following is true:

$$\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n(-1)^k \frac{(x+k)^2}{k^3}\right|\geq 1$$

Is this the right direction ? Any ideas ?

Comment: It would suffice to show that given any $N$, there is an $x$ such that ${(x+N)^2\over N^3}\ge1$. Then $\sum_{k=N}^N (-1)^k{(x+k)^2\over k^3}\ge1$; and thus the sum would not be uniformly Cauchy over $\Bbb R$. (Alternatively, if an infinite sum is uniformly convergent, then its terms converge uniformly to zero.)

Comment: @DavidMitra thank for this hint, I solved it !